# How to get the text from an XML element in go (structs tags)?

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

The following XML has an exemple of an element that has nested fields (title, author etc) and a text (Blah Blah...):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <book category="cooking">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
      Blah Blah Blah Bleh Blah
    </book>
```

I've coded this structure to decode this XML but I don't know which structure tag I should use in this case. I search in the docs but i have found nothing.

```
    type Book struct{
       t string `xml:"book>title"`
       p string `xml:"book>price"`
       y string `xml:"book>year"`
       a string `xml:"book>author"`
       blah string ???????
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal):

> If the XML element contains character data, that data is
>      accumulated in the first struct field that has tag ",chardata".
>      The struct field may have type []byte or string.
>      If there is no such field, the character data is discarded.

So, you can decode it with a struct as such:

```
type Book struct {
    Title   string   `xml:"title"`
    Price   string   `xml:"price"`
    Year    string   `xml:"year"`
    Author  string   `xml:"author"`
    Body    string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

(Note that fields you're unmarshaling into **must be exported**, i.e., must start with an uppercase letter, or they cannot be unmarshaled into.)

You can see an example here: https://play.golang.org/p/OlwSqnHsT7